# Custom loss function with gradient calculation

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I am trying to create the custom loss function in Keras. I want to compute the loss function based on the input and predicted output of the neural network. I created the custom loss function which takes the `y_true`, `y_pred` and `t` as the arguments. `t` is the variable that I would like to use for the custom loss function calculation. I have two parts in the loss function (please refer to the attached image)

I can create the first part of the loss function (which is the mean squared error). I would like to slice the `y_pred` tensor and assign it to three tensors (`y1_pred`, `y2_pred`, and `y3_pred`). Is there a way to do that directly in Keras or I have to use tensorflow for that? How can I calculate the gradient in keras? Do I need to create a session for computing `loss2`?

```
def customloss(y_true, y_pred, t):
    loss1 =  K.mean(K.square(y_pred - y_true), axis=-1)
    loss2 = tf.gradients(y1_pred, t) - y1_pred*y3_pred
    return loss1+loss2
```

Thank you.[image]

Comment: I don't really understand but I will tell you what I know and perhaps we can work from there.

I do not know how you are planning on passing the t-variable into the loss function, anything related to that I cannot help you with.

As far as the slicing goes, you can take columns from tensors like so:

y1_pred = y_pred[:, 0]
y2_pred = y_pred[:, 1]
y3_pred = y_pred[:, 2]